# Proper http status code

Tags: php, http-status-codes

I am developing an app using a third party package which assigns roles to users. If user has been assigned a role `1` is returned, otherwise `0` is returned.

I want to send back a message to clients if role assignment failed. Which [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) should I use?

EDIT: the third party package is like a black box to me and its not possible for me to figure out the failure reason . so maybe I need a generic status code

Comment: That depends on the reason why the assignment failed.

Comment: 666 616 69 11 ;) Trial and error maybe

Comment: @apokryfos the third party package is like  a black box to me.it just return 0 or 1

Comment: Success is 200 and error would be 500 since you don't know the reason it failed. Unless the 3rd party package returns a status code itself. Then you can use that.

Comment: Do not abuse HTTP codes unless you specifically need them. If you are only going to serve your responses as visual cues to end users that their request has been denied then just display an informative message and avoid messing with HTTP codes (the default 200 OK is fine for that).

Comment: @holodoc thanks,good point.but in my case i am implementing request using ajax.so i need status code to run ajax `done` or `fail` functions

Comment: @alex you can return 0 or 1 to ajax as a result and treat 0 as failure without needing an error code. You don't "need" to use status codes for error checking.

Comment: @alex Then implement a custom response API on the server side which will return something like `{'status':'SOME_CODE'}` and do your error handling on the client side based on the `SOME_CODE` clients receive in the response. There is absolutely zero need to use HTTP status codes in this case.

Comment: @holodoc what you say means ignore ajax `fail` function.am i right? because default `200` status code will lead to `done` function. so whats ajax `fail` function for?

Comment: @alex Yes. Add two separate control flows on your client side, one which will deal with actual AJAX response codes, in case some AJAX requests fail, and another one which will be inside the "200" status code block (which means `success`) which will deal with your custom `SOME_CODE`. This way you can implement an infinite number of status codes and still avoid messing with HTTP codes which can get really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about authentication, (which I think you are), from your own Wikipedia link:

```
401 Unauthorized
```

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication and Digest access authentication. 401 semantically means "unauthenticated", i.e. the user does not have the necessary credentials.
>
> Note: Some sites issue HTTP 401 when an IP address is banned from the website (usually the website domain) and that specific address is refused permission to access a website.

**Reference:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I added the article you referenced from Wikipedia to allow the OP to review additional details regarding the above mentioned status code and additional status codes.